# Removing '\n' from list item

Tags: python, list, python-3.2

I have a list and the last list item has a `\n` which I don't want.

```
print(list)
[somebody,please,help\n]   #what I have


print(list)
[somebody,please,help]      #desired list
```

Comment: I'm not sure what programming language is this?

Comment: sorry it's python 3.2 i'm an idiot

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-chomp-a-newline-in-python).

As an answer :

```
list[-1] = list[-1].rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strip function to remove any white space characters from the ends of the string for example:

```
str = str.strip()
```

So before printing, strip the string.  Perhaps you can save the stripped strings in a new list.

Comment: Also check out the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

str.strip() will remove the white space chars from the ends of the string. Don't forget that strip() returns a new string which needs to be assigned... You probably want.

```
for element in list:
    element = element.strip()
```