# Remove all line breaks from a long string of text

Tags: python

Basically, I'm asking the user to input a string of text into the console, but the string is very long and includes many line breaks.  How would I take the user's string and delete all line breaks to make it a single line of text.  My method for acquiring the string is very simple.

```
string = raw_input("Please enter string: ")
```

Is there a different way I should be grabbing the string from the user?  I'm running Python 2.7.4 on a Mac.

P.S. Clearly I'm a noob, so even if a solution isn't the most efficient, the one that uses the most simple syntax would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs

Comment: @NicYoung, that is similar but different. `strip` removes whitespace at the start and end of a string, not *inside* the string...

Answer (score 274, accepted):

How do you enter line breaks with `raw_input`? But, once you have a string with some characters in it you want to get rid of, just `replace` them.

```
>>> mystr = raw_input('please enter string: ')
please enter string: hello world, how do i enter line breaks?
>>> # pressing enter didn't work...
...
>>> mystr
'hello world, how do i enter line breaks?'
>>> mystr.replace(' ', '')
'helloworld,howdoienterlinebreaks?'
>>>
```

In the example above, I replaced all spaces. The string `'\n'` represents newlines. And `\r` represents carriage returns (if you're on windows, you might be getting these and a second `replace` will handle them for you!).

basically:

```
# you probably want to use a space ' ' to replace `\n`
mystring = mystring.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```

Note also, that it is a bad idea to call your variable `string`, as this shadows the module `string`. Another name I'd avoid but would love to use sometimes: `file`. For the same reason.

Comment: @QuestMonger's approach to replace both at once makes more sense to me. Why do two separate replaces: `mystring.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')`? Thanks

Comment: @information_interchange This approach works on Linux files that have `\n` but not `\r\n`.

Answer (score 67):

You can try using string replace:

```
string = string.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 46):

The **canonic answer**, in Python, would be :

```py
s = ''.join(s.splitlines())
```

It splits the string into lines (letting Python doing it according to its own best practices). Then you merge it. Two possibilities here:

- replace the newline by a whitespace (`' '.join()`)
- or without a whitespace (`''.join()`)

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. It is also OS independent

Comment: @Emer However it does remove \t at the same time which does not have to be the aim.

Answer (score 43):

You can split the string with no separator arg, which will treat consecutive whitespace as a single separator (including newlines and tabs). Then join using a space:

```
In : " ".join("\n\nsome    text \r\n with multiple whitespace".split())
Out: 'some text with multiple whitespace'
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 16):

updated based on `Xbello` comment:

```
string = my_string.rstrip('\r\n')
```

read more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm)

Answer (score 9):

Another option is regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("\n|\r", "", "Foo\n\rbar\n\rbaz\n\r")
'Foobarbaz'
```

Comment: more info on how to match consecutive linebreaks would be nice `r'[\n\r]+'` or even `r'\s+'` to replace any whitespace with a single space.

Answer (score 7):

If anybody decides to use `replace`, you should try `r'\n'` instead `'\n'`

```
mystring = mystring.replace(r'\n', ' ').replace(r'\r', '')
```

Comment: Why? I vaguely remember why this is a good idea, but we need to document it.

Comment: In my case, I needed to do this:
1. Get HTML code from DB
2. Get needed text from HTML
3. Remove all newline from text
4. Insert edited text to a spreadsheet document

And it didn't work properly, unless I used `r` ( "raw string literal"). 

Unfortunately, I have no idea why )

Comment: **NOTE** that `r'\r'` will match the literal "backslash r" -- not the "Carriage Return" character. Use either according to your input data.

Comment: this one worked. None of the others. Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

A method taking into consideration

- additional white characters at the beginning/end of string
- additional white characters at the beginning/end of every line
- various end-line characters

it takes such a multi-line string which may be messy e.g.

```
test_str = '\nhej ho \n aaa\r\n   a\n '
```

and produces nice one-line string

```
>>> ' '.join([line.strip() for line in test_str.strip().splitlines()])
'hej ho aaa a'
```

UPDATE:
To fix multiple new-line character producing redundant spaces:

```
' '.join([line.strip() for line in test_str.strip().splitlines() if line.strip()])
```

This works for the following too
`test_str = '\nhej ho \n aaa\r\n\n\n\n\n   a\n '`

Comment: This doesn't handle the case of contiguous line feeds in the middle of the string. Two line feeds result in two contiguous blanks in the output. Try "test_str = '\nhej ho \n aaa\r\n\n   a\n '"

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `rstrip()` is that it does not work in all cases (as I myself have seen few). Instead you can use

```py
text = text.replace("\n"," ")
```

This will remove all new line `'\n'` with a space.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions is the fastest way to do this

```
s='''some kind   of
string with a bunch\r of

  
 extra spaces in   it'''

re.sub(r'\s(?=\s)','',re.sub(r'\s',' ',s))
```

result:

```
'some kind of string with a bunch of extra spaces in it'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace \r\n or \n with a space, reduce multiple spaces to one and trim spaces from the beginning and end:

```
import re
text = re.sub(r'\r?\n',' ',text)
text = re.sub(r' +',' ',text).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to remove ALL the signs: lf cr crlf.

```
# Pythonic:
r'\n', r'\r', r'\r\n'
```

Some texts must have breaks, but you probably need to join broken lines to keep particular sentences together.

Therefore it is natural that line breaking happens after priod, semicolon, colon, but not after comma.

My code considers above conditions. Works well with texts copied from pdfs.
Enjoy!:

```
def unbreak_pdf_text(raw_text):
    """ the newline careful sign removal tool

    Args:
        raw_text (str): string containing unwanted newline signs: \\n or \\r or \\r\\n
        e.g. imported from OCR or copied from a pdf document.

    Returns:
        _type_: _description_
    """
    pat = re.compile((r"[, \w]\n|[, \w]\r|[, \w]\r\n"))
    breaks = re.finditer(pat, raw_text)

    processed_text = raw_text
    raw_text = None

    for i in breaks:
        processed_text = processed_text.replace(i.group(), i.group()[0]+" ")

    return processed_text
```