# Python code that decrypts RSA encrypted file in chunks of 64 bit using a private exponent and modulus

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have an encrypted file that I am trying to decode as part of an experiment. After working hard and long, I have been able to extract the private exponent from the public key since the modulus was small:

openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -text -noout < public_key.pem
   Public-Key: (64 bit)
   Modulus: 16513720463601767803 (0xe52c8544a915157b)
   Exponent: 65537

Now, I have:

```
 Factors: 3917781347 x 4215069449 
 Private exponent: 9440767265896423601
```

Now, to derive the plaintext, I need to raise each 64-bit block of ciphertext to the private exponent mod the modulus. I am trying to write a Python script that will do this for me in hex data form.

This is the code I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

 file = open('encrypted.hex', 'r')
 c = file.readline()
 d = 0x830457cf1ae460b1
 N = 0xe52c8544a915157b

 m = hex(pow(c, d, N)).rstrip("L")

 f = open('new.try', 'w')
 f.write(m)
 f.close()
```

I have used `xxd` to extract the hex data from the ciphertext file:
     xxd -p > encrypted.hex

This created a hex dump of the file called 'encrypted.hex'. The contents of this file begin like this:

```
7d4554292d7b9f980ed049cea0f968cf438b6fc312cf2028ce5ce2fe9f38
387b72a01bf6564f25884a2cacd187c2eeccd0cf78c2a74785f18d5e72b5
270ac3e45b6f7505347b38ec7684b1af206d73ea4a84cd59b50be56d7abf
74a569868406ab2b17846c9e448fe1392b21dac0b10fbb733536c99e598b
683be7400a1ad55c42faa171becd803b8b8f4a1fa512a33222ec042486c5
672f6200d4f00e2994b6d247a44edb6ce90795bde7ccda4433cf6fca8362
f87c68f9df6418c4f0b8fb9da39a1d173fea2b1466e646f01e2dc7fb0499
311d35ec75c15c5910b2d3e0c662de0b3b1716bab44faa2a36538bb44f6a
3c3abd37692cf95fa075b58485ad983533782d7bf51e10c0e3b18ccec972
```

...and so on. The tool 'xxd' created the hexdump and inserted line breaks I think.

So, 'c' is the `ciphertext`, 'd' is the `private exponent`, 'N' is the `modulus` and 'm' is supposed to contain the plaintext hex bytes.

However, the script gives me this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 8, in <module>
   m = hex(pow(c, d, N)).rstrip("L")
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'str', 'long', 'long'
```

Could anyone correct my Python script so that it is able to decipher the ciphertext as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `c` is a hex string with a multiple of 16 characters, you can [split it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475354) every 16 characters (64-bit) and then convert this [hex chunk into an int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/209550) to run your textbook RSA on it. Since your hex file has line breaks, you first need to [remove those line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566356). You can read the whole file like with `file.read()` instead of `file.readline()`.

Final code

```
n = 16
c = c.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
m = [hex(pow(int(c[i:i+n], 16), d, N)).rstrip("L") for i in range(0, len(c), n)]

f = open('new.try', 'w')
f.write(''.join(m))
f.close()
```

Comment: Obligatory Doomsday notice: Textbook RSA is horribly broken and a proper padding scheme such as OAEP must be used. Keys smaller than 2048-bit are not recommended for anything serious.

Comment: The file containing the ciphertext is too large, and contains line breaks (\n). So, readline only read one line I think, because I see only one line as the plaintext output. How can I read the whole ciphertext file, removing the newline (\n) characters?

Comment: Done! This hexdump that you see above in the edit, has been taken using tool 'xxd -p'. It inserted line breaks in there I think. This hexdump is from .enc (encrypted) file that I need to decrypt in chunks of 64 bits.