# Using textract to get text from pptx. and docx. without tags

Tags: python, tags, powerpoint, text-extraction

I use the following code to get a string from docx. or pptx. (since textract does not correctly work with non-acsii symbols I use the solution described [here](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/203)):

```
import textract as txt
text = txt.process("D:\Corpus\Exposee.pptx")
text = text.decode("utf8")
```

Then I call `text` and get the string that looks as follows:

```
'Syntaktische Besonderheiten \n\ndes Maschinellen Verstehens \n\nder Deutschen Sprache \n\nin der Multilingualen Perspektive\n\nMarvin Teller\n\nForschungsfrage\n\nW\n\nelche\n\n \n\nEigenschaften\n\n \n\n\n\n\tder \n\nsyntaktischen\n\n \n\nStruktur\n\n der \n\n
```

(shortened)

I'd like to have the string without tags like `\n` and `\t`, how to do that?

Sorry in advance for possible duplication/naiveness

Comment: You are calling it as its base version, the \n allow paragraphs, try using print(text) then you'll see what I mean

Comment: But if you do want to remove it, do text = text.remove()

Comment: @TommyLawrence Thank you for suggestion! However, I get "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'" while applying 'remove' to the string (text)

Comment: Ok, sorry, it's replace, do text = text.replace("\n", "")

Comment: @TommyLawrence Yep, thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all line breaks from a long string of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566268/remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-long-string-of-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments: 
The text you see is in the form you have extracted from the file. The \n allows you to have paragraphs. By putting that text (string) and printing it, you can see it makes paragraphs. To get rid of it, you need to do text (variable) = text.replace("\n", ""), that will replace the "\n" with nothing "".