# Concatenation - Python

Tags: python, concatenation

I have written a code that returns a phrase depending on the length of a name. Problem is, I can't submit it unless i fix this tiny error.

Here's what I've written:

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')

if len(name) <= 3:

  print ('Hi',name,', you have a short name.')

elif len(name) > 8:

  print ('Hi',name,', you have a long name.')

elif len(name) >= 4:

  print ('Hi',name,', nice to meet you.')
```

For example: When i type in a 3 letter name such as 'Lin' it reruns the following

> "Hi Lin*(space)*, you have a short name."

**I wish to get rid of the *(space)* and have it return:**

> "Hi Lin, you have a short name."

I think the error lies with my concatenation and it automatically ads a space after the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're are right, print(x, y, z) will sequentially print x, y and z with a space inbetween. As you suggest, concatenate your name to your greeting, and then print the greeting:

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
if len(name) <= 3:
  greeting = "Hi {}, you have a short name.".format(name)

elif len(name) > 8:
  greeting = "Hi {}, you have a long name.".format(name)

elif len(name) >= 4:
  greeting = "Hi {}, nice to meet you.".format(name)

print(greeting)
```

Comment: That's much better, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function prints a space between its arguments. You can explicitly concatenate the strings to control the separation:

```
print('Hi ' + name + ', you have a short name.')
```

or use string formatting:

```
print('Hi {}, you have a short name.'.format(name))
```

Comment: Thanks, i'd give you an upvote if i could :)

Answer (score 0):

For your input is is also possible to get rid of the whitespaces with the strip() function

```
name = name.strip()
```

[How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings in Python like this:

```
print('Hello ' + name + ', you have a wonderful name!')
```

Or, without the parenthesis:

```
print 'Hello '  + name + ', you have a wonderful name!'
```

There's various other tricky things you can do, but for something like this just having '+' signs will do.