# Python Whitespace Issues

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I have a py script which amongst other things parses a value from a HTML table using BeautifulSoup.

The value which is being returned (outTempReal) seems to have some whitespace after the value. I know this due to the print I use...

```
print "Temp 1 =", avgtemperatures[0],
print "Temp 2 =", avgtemperatures[1],
print "Temp 3 =", avgtemperatures[2],
print "Temp 4 =", avgtemperatures[3],
print "Temp 5 =", avgtemperatures[4],
print "Outside Temp =", outTempReal,
print "METAR Temp =", currentTemp,
print "Plant Room Temp =", avgtemperatures[5],
print "Flow Temp =", avgtemperatures[6],
print "Return Temp =", avgtemperatures[7]
```

Which returns the following...

```
Temp 1 = 79.625 Temp 2 = 79.1456666667 Temp 3 = 31.229 Temp 4 = 28.125 Temp 5 = 27.2706666667 Outside Temp = 4.8        METAR Temp = 5 Plant Room Temp = 16.7913333333 Flow Temp = 13.875 Return Temp = 18.312
```

You can see that after the Outside Temp = 4.8 there is whitespace before the next print value.

This is the code used to get the value in the first place...

```
table = soup.find('table')
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
            col = row.findAll('td')
            if len(col) >= 2:
                    time = col[1].string
                    temp = col[2].string
    outTempReal = re.sub(r'[^0-9\-\d.\s+]',' ', temp)
```

I have tried the following two methods to remove the whitespace but no joy...

```
outTempReal.strip()
re.sub('\s+',' ',outTempReal)
```

I really need this value to be just the decimal number because it is used to update a RRD.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know python but replacing `\s+` with ` ` does work for any whitespace.

Comment: Still the same... sorry!

Comment: It's not a problem with the regex though, but rather probably your way of implementing the replace. If I knew python I could help, I'm just telling you the regex is fine. Maybe you need to escape it with double slashes like `\\s+`?

Comment: This is where bach scripting will come in handy because you can do something like `tr -s ' '` Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1185528/2089675) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8270146/2089675) for python version of it

Answer (score 0):

`.rstrip()` will trim any trailing whitespace:

```
>>> thing = 'value              '
>>> thing
'value              '
>>> thing.rstrip()
'value'
```

Comment: Hi, Still returns the following from the print.... Temp 1 = 77.062 Temp 2 = 75.437 Temp 3 = 33.25 Temp 4 = 32.187 Temp 5 = 31.0 Outside Temp = 4.5        METAR Temp = 5 Plant Room Temp = 16.875 Flow Temp = 13.375 Return Temp = 34.5413333333
So it looks like it doesn't work. Could this be something other than 'whitespace' ?

Comment: Looks like the formatting of the comments does not show the space. It's still there!