# Python - Split Strings into parameters

Tags: python, string, split, numbers

I am new to Python and I have a string split problem which I need help

```
input = "\"filename.txt\", 1234,8973,\"Some Description \""
```

`input` contains both strings & numbers, and there might be cases where  leading and tailing spaces exist

expected output should be

```
['filename.txt', '1234', '8973', 'Some Description']
```

Can split do the job or i need regular expressions?

Comment: Could there be a comma in a `\"string\"` between two commas?

Comment: Why dont you first try `split` and see if it works instead of asking? Takes 10 seconds to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> [s.strip(' "') for s in input.split(',')]
['filename.txt', '1234', '8973', 'Some Description']
```

If it's guaranteed that no commas appear within your quoted parts, this will do.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to handle input like that; it handles quoting, can be taught about leading whitespace, and trailing whitespace can be removed afterwards:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(inputstring.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True)
row = next(reader)  # get just the first row
res = [c.strip() for c in row]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> inputstring = '"filename.txt", 1234,8973,"Some Description "'
>>> reader = csv.reader(inputstring.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True)
>>> row = next(reader)
>>> [c.strip() for c in row]
['filename.txt', '1234', '8973', 'Some Description']
```

This has the added advantage that you can have commas *in the values*, provided they are quoted:

```
>>> with_commas = '"Hello, world!", "One for the money, two for the show"'
>>> reader = csv.reader(with_commas.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True)
>>> [c.strip() for c in next(reader)]
['Hello, world!', 'One for the money, two for the show']
```

The `csv.reader()` object takes an *iterable* as the first argument; I used the [`str.splitlines()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to turn a (potentially multiline) string into a list; you could also just use `[inputstring]` if your input string is always just one line.

Comment: Another 40 lashes for input ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: tell that to the OP! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) for this..

```
In [9]: input = "\"filename.txt\", 1234,8973,\"Some Description \""
In [11]: input = map(lambda x: x.strip(), input.split(','))
In [14]: input = map(lambda x: x.strip('"'), input)
In [16]: input = map(lambda x: x.strip(), input)
In [17]: input
Out[17]: ['filename.txt', '1234', '8973', 'Some Description']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like

```
li=input.split(",")
```

this will fetch you

```
li=['"filename.txt"', ' 1234', '8973', '"Some Description "']
```

then use ltrim and rtrim accordingly see [How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Use the re module.

Try the following code:

```
import re
filter(lambda x: x != '', re.split(",| |\"", input))
```

The output will be:

```
['filename.txt', '1234', '8973', 'Some', 'Description']
```

Comment: if there are "spaces" in filename and description, this code will not work properly

Answer (score 0):

```
map(str.strip, input.replace('"','').split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just using `eval()` function

```
input = "\"filename.txt\", 1234,8973,\"Some Description \""
>>> list(eval(input))
['filename.txt', 1234, 8973, 'Some Description ']
```