# Remove extra spaces using regex

Tags: python, regex

Product Name:

```
"                Samsung Floor Standing Invertor Air Conditioner - 2.0 Ton - AF-28FSSDAWKXFA (Q-9000) - White (Brand Warranty)                  "
```

I have this product name in which i need to remove all the spaces before start and also after last character ")". Regex is compulsory for me. I am trying to achieve all this in python.

**Note:** Or lets say i need to get only the title without starting and ending spaces.

Comment: Which engine are you using ?

Comment: why don't you use `strip` ? regex is'n neccesary

Comment: @PedroLobito What do you mean by engine? I am using python though, if language is what you are asking about.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. I don't know the usage of strip? Would you please elaborate?

Comment: `Regex is compulsory for me` Why so, may I ask when there are easier methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs)

Comment: @toddlermenot I find implementing regex in python easy.

Comment: There's no need to use a regex for this.

Comment: @MansoorAkram a example using regex [demo regex](https://regex101.com/r/dH8nV4/1) ..... but for this is better to use `strip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Remove extra spaces using regex

There's no need to use a regex for this.

[.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) is what you need.

```
print yourString.strip()
#Samsung Floor Standing Invertor Air Conditioner - 2.0 Ton - AF-28FSSDAWKXFA (Q-9000) - White (Brand Warranty)
```

---

**LIVE PYTHON DEMO**

http://ideone.com/iEmH0i

---

```
string.strip(s[, chars])
```

> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters
>   removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are
>   removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters
>   in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this
>   method is called on.

Comment: can you please define **"this did not worked"** ? what's the error ?

Comment: No error but it did not removed any whitespace and returned the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you *must* use regex, you can use this:

```
import re
s = "                Samsung Floor Standing Invertor Air Conditioner - 2.0 Ton - AF-28FSSDAWKXFA (Q-9000) - White (Brand Warranty)                  "
s = re.sub("^\s+|\s+$","",s)
print(s)
```

Result :

> "Samsung Floor Standing Invertor Air Conditioner - 2.0 Ton -
>   AF-28FSSDAWKXFA (Q-9000) - White (Brand Warranty)"

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: a solution using regex (for this is better `strip`)

```
import re
p = re.compile('\s+((\s?\S+)+)\s+')
test_str = "                Samsung Floor Standing Invertor Air Conditioner - 2.0 Ton - AF-28FSSDAWKXFA (Q-9000) - White (Brand Warranty)                  "
subst = "\\1"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
print (result)
```

you get,

```
Samsung Floor Standing Invertor Air Conditioner - 2.0 Ton - AF-28FSSDAWKXFA (Q-9000) - White (Brand Warranty)
```