# Conditional statement not working with input function

Tags: python, input, conditional-statements

i'm just writing a simple program that should give me a random integer between 1 and 10 if i input the value of 'r'in code. here's what i have:

```
import sys, random

from random import *

def randomly():
    return (randint(1, 10))

while True:
    x = input("input string ")
    x = str(x)
    print (x)

    if x == 'r':
        print ("your generated number is", randomly())

    else:
        break
```

i know there's just something small i'm overlooking. but i can't figure out what. the randomly function works. and if i replace the 'r' conditional with an integer (i used 1) convert x with int(x) and then input 1 the program works fine. like so:

```
import sys, random

from random import *

def randomly():
    return (randint(1, 10))

while True:
    x = input("input number ")
    x = int(x)
    print (x)

    if x == 1:
        print ("your generated number is", randomly())

    else:
        break
```

for some reason the if conditional won't respond to my string. i tried x.lower() and it still won't work, while it's true that just using the method i described before with the integer would work fine. it frustrates me that my code won't work the way i want it to. for what it's worth i checked len(x) and it says 2 when i input a single character(r). i'm fairly novice to python but i have the knowledge i need, at least, to write a program like this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

i'm using visual studio 2015 
python environment: python 3.2

this is my first question here. i searched to the best of my capabilities and couldn't find an answer. i apologize in advance if there is anything wrong with my question.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also if you are using python 3 input is already a `str`, if you are not using python3 your code would error unless you had a variable `r` defined somehwere

Comment: Can you check your python version (`import sys; print(sys.version)`)? The `input` builtin behaves differently depending on the version, and the behavior you describe looks like that of python2 actually.

Comment: What is `print(x)` printing?

Comment: thank you for the speedy response, there is no error it just executes the else: break. like i said, the code works fine. the if jsut won't execute with any kind of string i input.

Comment: Are you sure you are using python3? What does `sys.version` output as per spectras suggestion output?

Comment: I'm running the example successfully: `input string r
r
your generated number is 9
input string r
r
your generated number is 9
input string r
r
your generated number is 2
input string r
r
your generated number is 9
input string `

Running it on `Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin`

Comment: You mention the length is 2 when you only input a single character. I've never used python myself, but can you output which the two different characters are? I suspect one of them might be a newline of some sort, especially if when you print it all you see is the "r". As far as how to handle that, I have no idea other than verifying the first element in your string is "r".

Comment: Works fine for me (using python 3).

Comment: i don't understand what's wrong. print(x) was for me, to check my input. print(sys.version) prints: 3.2 <r32:88445, feb 20 2011, 21:29:02> [MSC v.1500 32 bit<intel>]

Comment: What happens if after you convert it to a string, you use the strip command on it?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs

Comment: This seems more like a visual studio problem  than a python one if you are using python3

Comment: => running your program on Python 3.2 on a Ubuntu box gives the expected results. *points at microsoft visual studio*

Comment: I've copied your code, and everything works as expected.

Comment: thanks you all, i am so sorry to have wasted your time. i was assuming i did something wrong but many of you claim the code works fine. i'll be trying it in a different IDE. again, thank you for your time.

Comment: That was no waste, it's not like you had a simple typo or something. Plus, question was clear with code samples and showed some research. Keep going. And welcome on SO, by the way.

Comment: Is there a newline or something that got tacked on without you knowing? Try using `x.strip() == 'r'`.

Comment: i got the code to work! using strip() after the input worked for me. must have been a blank space added for some reason. i don't know if it's my keyboard layout or vs2015. but at least i found a workaround. thank you all so much!