# How to trim leading and trailing whitespaces in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

hi wanna to remove leading and trailing spaces in csv files

```
24333,   116,    47,MCD,00000000000000000017996,   112
24333,   116,    47,MCD,00000000000000610036485,   112  
24333,   116,    47,MCD,00000000000000610036485,   112
```

can any one help the code i tried

```
import csv

csvfile= open('strip.csv','r')
csvfile1= open('strip11.csv','w') 
stripped = (row.strip() for row in csvfile)
reader = csv.reader(stripped,delimiter=' ')
writer= csv.writer(csvfile1)
for row in reader:
   writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: `writer.writerow([e.strip() for e in row])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs)

Comment: added the above code m getting the output as  comma are added in  the spcaes part below"24333,",,,"116,",,,,"47,MCD,00000000000000000017996,",,,112

"24333,",,,"116,",,,,"47,MCD,00000000000000610036485,",,,112

"24333,",,,"116,",,,,"47,MCD,00000000000000610036485,",,,112

Comment: i  chaged the code has below, stripping hwppening perfectly but new empty row is appending after each row in csv file . can any one help below is my code                                                                                import csv
csvfile= open('strip.csv','r')
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
next(reader, None)
csvfile1= open('strip4.csv','w') 
stripped = (row.strip() for row in csvfile)
reader = csv.reader(stripped,delimiter=',')
writer= csv.writer(csvfile1)
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([e.strip() for e in row])

Answer (score 7):

The magic comes from applying `strip` on each item in each row record.

Stripping a string is done usually like `"  abc ".strip`. To refer to the `strip` method without having actual string at hand, one can `import string` and then use `string.strip`.

The `map(string.strip, list_of_strings_to_strip)` applies the `strip` to each item in the record and returns them in a list.

```
>>> import string
>>> rec = ["  a  ", "  b  ", "  c  "]
>>> map(string.strip, rec)
["a", "b", "c"]
```

The complete working example for your data:

```
import csv
import string

with open("data.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    with open("stripped.csv", "w") as fo:
        writer = csv.writer(fo)
        for rec in reader:
            writer.writerow(map(string.strip, rec))
```

The `with open(...` are so called context managers ensuring, that the created file descriptor will get closed regardless of possible failure during the inner block execution.

Resulting file looks like:

```
24333,116,47,MCD,00000000000000000017996,112
24333,116,47,MCD,00000000000000610036485,112
24333,116,47,MCD,00000000000000610036485,112
```

Comment: i used above code also still empty row is coming can any one help on he same .Why m getting empty row after each row having data

Comment: @prasanna.1024kt Make sure, you copy paste my complete example. It is likely, you mixed your and mine solution, and in your solution you iterate about file lines (which include newline at the end) and mine iterates about csv records (which have the new line stripped for reading and also manage new lines properly when writing). Note, that this newline stripping is done by `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` and has nothing to do with `string.strip`.