# Strip all whitespaces EXCLUDING tabs

Tags: python, string, removing-whitespace

Just a (hopefully) simple question.
Doing some messing around with Python and I just want to know how I can strip both the left side and right side of my strings of all whitespace **except** for tabs, or rather `\t`.

I understand I can probably loop recursively with replace, but that's messy. Theres got to be a simpler way.

Basically just removing `\n, ,\r,`...etc except for `\t`.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.sub`:

```
import re

string = 'Hello\nThis is   a sample\tstring\n\r!'
print(re.sub('[ \n\r]', '', string))
```

Comment: Short and sweet! My only issue is, is that the whitespace in the regex seems to be picking up my tabs too, and im **sure** their tabs and not converted to four whitespaces...

Comment: This solution will also remove spaces, \n and \r on the inside of the string, not just from the left and right side.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
s = "  \t a string example\t  "
s = s.strip(' \n\r')
```

This will strip any space, \n, or \r characters from the left-hand side, right-hand side, or both sides of the string.

Reference: [How to trim whitespace (including tabs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-to-trim-whitespace-including-tabs)

Comment: Lovely! Thanks for that. Didn't realise the `strip()` function took args.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.strip(' ').strip('\n').strip('\r')#this will return a copy of string with '\r' and '\b' removed from left side and right side.
```

See:[string.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

Comment: Will also strip `\t` and will not strip `\b` as `strip()` will strip all white space chars which includes tabs.