# Removing new lines only at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I've tried

```
if string[0] == "\n":
    string = string[1:]
```

I don't think `strip()` and `rtrim()` is what I want because they'd either remove all occurrences of `\n` or only at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
string = "\n\nHello"
new_string = re.sub("\n+", '', string)
```

Output:

```
'Hello'
```

This will work for any number of `\n` at the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`str.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip). Exact same as `strip()` except it strips from the left only, not both directions.

```
>>> s = '\n\nhi\n'
>>> s.lstrip('\n')
'hi\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [How do I trim whitespace with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace-with-python)

But basically: `string = string.lstrip('\n')`