# ValueError: could not convert string to float error in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm trying to create a program that asks for numbers to make an average at the end and gives the average when a blank space is entered. My code looks like this:

```
number_of_numbers = 0
sum_of_numbers = 0
zero_number = 0
while number_of_numbers > -1:
    decimal_number = input('Input a number: ')
    if decimal_number == (''):
        decimal_number = zero_number
    else:
        decimal_number = float(decimal_number)
    number_of_numbers = number_of_numbers + 1
    sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + decimal_number
    if decimal_number == '':
        break
print((sum_of_numbers + zero_number) / number_of_numbers)
```

But it keeps saying that the empty space is a string. I tried to get around this by assigning a blank space a new variable that counts as zero but for some reason I keep getting the error. It also gives me a division by 0 for some reason as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because when I run it, I don't get `ValueError`, I get `NameError: name 'zero_number' is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry yes I fixed that problem by changing the condition of the while loop and fixed that issue. The new code is in the question now. Thank you for your help though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trim whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace)

Comment: Your code will never hit the `break` statement because you reassign `decimal_number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `break` statement within your first `if` and use `if not decimal_number:` instead of checking for `''` since empty strings are falsy, so they are considered false in a Boolean context.

Also check if `number_of_numbers` is `0` before trying to divide.

```
number_of_numbers = 0
sum_of_numbers = 0
zero_number = 0
while number_of_numbers > -1:
    decimal_number = input('Input a number: ')
    if not decimal_number:
        decimal_number = zero_number
        ## number_of_numbers = 1
        break
    else:
        decimal_number = float(decimal_number)
    number_of_numbers = number_of_numbers + 1
    sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers + decimal_number
if number_of_numbers == 0:
    print('Cannot Divide by zero!')
else:
    print((sum_of_numbers + zero_number) / number_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to stop when you hit an empty space. That's `' '`, not `''`. You're testing for `''`, which isn't an empty space, it's just a string of length 0.

The better solution would be to *strip all whitespace* from the input, and *then* check if it's an empty string afterwards (e.g. there was nothing there except whitespace). You'd replace the line

```
if decimal_number == (''):
```

with

```
if decimal_number.strip() == (''):
```

The `.strip()` method simply removes whitespace from both the front and the back of a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to increment number_of_numbers when you got blank space **''** as input (you do this in your code). That's why I provide two versions.

1) Increment number_of_numbers on blank space:

```
number_of_numbers = 0
sum_of_numbers = 0
while True:
    decimal_number = input('Input a number: ')
    if decimal_number == '':
        number_of_numbers += 1
        break            
    try:
        sum_of_numbers += float(decimal_number)        
        number_of_numbers += 1
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong Input. Try Again')
        continue
print(sum_of_numbers / number_of_numbers)
```

2) Don't increment number_of_numbers on blank space (need to check for zero in sum_of_numbers):

```
number_of_numbers = 0
sum_of_numbers = 0
while True:
    decimal_number = input('Input a number: ')
    if decimal_number == '':
        break        
    try:
        sum_of_numbers += float(decimal_number)        
        number_of_numbers += 1
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong Input. Try Again')
        continue
if number_of_numbers == 0:
    print('No values to compute Average')
else:
    print(sum_of_numbers / number_of_numbers)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much