# Write some regex to clean list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list containing text data from a docx file.  How can I apply some regex or some lambda function to go through this whole list and 'clean it'; meaning, I'd like to take out `\t` and `\n`

```
['\tSA   [WP5]\t\t\n', "<class 'docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph'>\n", '\t\tCOUNTRY:\n', "<class 'docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph'>\n", '\n']
```

so that my output looks like:

```
['SA   [WP5]', "<class 'docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph'>", 'COUNTRY:', "<class 'docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph'>", '']
```

Comment: Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
[x.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '') for  x in lst]
```

would do it, without the need for regex.