# How to strip trailing space from keys in a Python Dictionary?

Tags: python, io

I have the following data in a text file named "`user_table.txt`":

```
Jane - valentine4Me
Billy 
Billy - slick987
Billy - monica1600Dress
 Jason - jason4evER
Brian - briguy987321CT
Laura - 100LauraSmith
   Charlotte - beutifulGIRL!
  Christoper - chrisjohn
```

And, the following code to read this data and create a Python dictionary:

```
users = {}

with open("user_table.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
    
        # if there is no password
        if ('-' in line) == False:
            continue
    
        # otherwise read into a dictionary
        else:
            key, value = line.split('-')
            users[key] = value
            
k= users.keys()
print(k)

if 'Jane' in k:
    print('she is not in the dict')
if 'Jane ' in k:
    print('she *is* in the dict')
```

I see that there are trailing spaces in the keys:

```
dict_keys(['Jane ', 'Billy ', 'Jason ', 'Brian ', 'Laura ', 'Charlotte ', 'Christoper '])
she *is* in the dict
```

What is the best way to remove the spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I trim whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `key, value = line.split('-')` to `key, value = line.split(' - ')`.

Answer (score 3):

try to change:

```
key, value = line.split('-')
```

to

```
key, value = [i.strip() for i in line.split('-')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this:

```
key, value = line.split('-')
users[key] = value
```

by this:

```
k=line.split('-')
users[k[0].strip()]=k[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
users[key] = value
```

to

```
users[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

This will generalize your code in case there is no space on either or both sides of '-' in split().