# How to find and add new line in python if have spaces before

Tags: python

I have some trouble with my code. In "line1 and line2" before the text in file have some spaces, how i can ignore them?

Ex.:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
         </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1">
    <bindings>
```

And these spaces interfere with code to find line1 and line2.

Below is my code

```
with open("xxx", "r+") as f:
a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
index = 1
line1 = '<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1">'
line2 = "<bindings>"
for item in a:
    if item.startswith(line1 and line2):
        a.insert(index, '<simple name="java:global/nbs/app/portal/config/routes"\n\tvalue="C:\\nbs\\app\\portal\\routes.properties"/>')
        break
    index += 1
f.seek(0)
for line in a:
    f.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove leading whitespace in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959215/how-do-i-remove-leading-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trimming a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/trimming-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The `lstrip()` method will remove leading whitespaces, newline and tab characters on a string beginning:

```
>>> '     hello world!'.lstrip()
'hello world!
```

Reference: [How do I remove leading whitespace in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959215/how-do-i-remove-leading-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: No, i need ignore spaces not in my script, i need ignore spaces in file. When i delete spaces, the script is working fine, but if i don't delete them, the script does not find these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]`

into this

`a = [x.strip() for x in f]`

**Explnation:**
`rstrip()` only trims the whitespaces on the right side, what you need is `strip()` method which strips whitespaces on both sides.

Comment: ahahhah, he delete all spaces in file) i needn't do it.

Comment: Can are u help me please?