# Natural sorting of a list in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, natural-sort

I am trying to sort a list:

```
[
    '[fc] EDW Ratio (10 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (45 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (60 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (25 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (20 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (30 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (15 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW output factor (60 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] Quality index'
]
```

using the first part of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside):

But the list is ending up like this:

```
[
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (15 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (20 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (25 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (30 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (45 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (60 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW output factor (60 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] Quality index', 
    '[fc] EDW Ratio (10 degrees)'
]
```

whereas I want ***EDW Ratio (10 degrees)*** to end up at the start of the list after sorting (index position 0).

How can this be done?

My code includes the following:

```
#
# Method to define natural sorting used to sort lists
#
def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    '''
    alist.sort(key=natural_keys) sorts in human order
    http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html
    (See Toothy's implementation in the comments)
    '''
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]

    .
    .
    .


    tname_list = test_names.split(",") # this outputs the exact first (unsorted) list shown above

    tname_list.sort(key=natural_keys) # use human sorting defined above. This outputs the second list shown above.
```

Comment: hi @2one, can you show us your code, please?

Comment: What does `natural_keys` return for each of your input strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, but your data look incorrect: all the entries have a leading whitespace, which implies they are "before" the one you identify as least, that actually have no leading whitespace.

If the data is fine as they are I suggest you to revise the code to ignore leading whitespaces (check this: [How do I remove leading whitespace in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959215/how-do-i-remove-leading-whitespace-in-python)).

Comment: Some other good answers to make the code more robust but this was the issue for now. I added in line of code as indicated below and that had the intended effect. Thanks.

Comment: `tname_list = [x.lstrip() for x in tname_list] # remove white space from start of list entries before sort`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/%60) (full disclosure, I am the author).  Your data is also a bit messy, you need to remove the leading whitespace to normalize all the entries.

```
from natsort import natsorted
data = [
    '[fc] EDW Ratio (10 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (45 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (60 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (25 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (20 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (30 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW Ratio (15 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] EDW output factor (60 degrees)', 
    ' [fc] Quality index'
]
data_sorted = natsorted(data, key=lambda x: x.lstrip())
```

Outputs

```
[
 '[fc] EDW Ratio (10 degrees)',
 ' [fc] EDW Ratio (15 degrees)',
 ' [fc] EDW Ratio (20 degrees)',
 ' [fc] EDW Ratio (25 degrees)',
 ' [fc] EDW Ratio (30 degrees)',
 ' [fc] EDW Ratio (45 degrees)',
 ' [fc] EDW Ratio (60 degrees)',
 ' [fc] EDW output factor (60 degrees)',
 ' [fc] Quality index',
]
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look at that in the future.

Comment: +1 for the lambda key. I sorted a list of numeric strings using `key=lambda x: int(x)`.  Output without the key: `10, 11, 12, 13, 3, 4`. Output with the key: `3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13`.

Comment: I used natsort for quite a few projects...  But in my current project, I don't see any obvious method for natsort to work?  I don't need to sort a list, but I need to have a string converted into a natsort key?  (eg so that I can have a database present the data in a human sorted view using raw SQL... The natsort key will be placed into a table column which is used as the sorting field)

I see the humansorted in the API, but that's returning a list...  I could be missing it, but I did take a look through the code...

Comment: @BenjaminSchollnick It sounds like you are looking for [`natsort_keygen`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#natsort-keygen)? If not, then you likely need to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `natural_keys` to only return the numerical part of the string as an `int`. You should use `int()` for the conversion instead of `atoi()` which returns the ascii code of a character.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run into trouble if any of your strings contain more than one number, or put the numbers at the beginning or end of the string.  That's because Python can't compare an `int` and `str` to each other.  Your key function should return both as a tuple or list.

```
def atoi(text):
    return (int(text), '') if text.isdigit() else (math.nan, text)
```

`math.nan` is special, because it will never compare less than an actual number.

Comment: Thanks might extend to incorporate this too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def get_numbers(texto):
    return int(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', texto)[0])
        
def sort_list(l):
    dicto = {}
    for i in l:
        dicto[get_numbers(i)] = i
    lista = []
    for i in sorted(list(dicto.keys())):
        lista.append(dicto[i])
    return lista

sort_list(frames)
```

NOTE that it will only work for the first serie of numbers ... "peter123jjj111" will only take 123 into account