# Anyone know a good regex to remove extra whitespace?

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Substitute multiple whitespace with single whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077897/substitute-multiple-whitespace-with-single-whitespace-in-python)

trying to figure out how to write a regex that given the string:

```
"hi     this       is a  test"
```

I can turn it into

```
"hi this is a test"
```

where the whitespace is normalized to just one space

any ideas? thanks so much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import re    
re.sub("\s+"," ",string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a regex?

I'd just use

```
new_string = " ".join(re.split(s'\s+', old_string.strip()))
```

Comment: You still use a regular expression ;)

Comment: I thought that as I was writing it out, actually :)

Answer (score 0):

sed

```
 sed 's/[  ]\{2,\}/ /g'
```