# Compress whitespaces in string

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Substitute multiple whitespace with single whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077897/substitute-multiple-whitespace-with-single-whitespace-in-python)

How do I compress multiple whitespaces to 1 whitespace, in python?

For example, let's say I have a string

```
"some   user entered     text"
```

and I want that to become

```
"some user entered text"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
' '.join("some   user entered     text".split())
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("\s+"," ","some   user entered     text")
'some user entered text'
>>>
```

EDIT:

This will also replace line breaks and tabs etc.

If you specifically want spaces / tabs you could use

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("[ \t]+"," ","some   user entered     text")
'some user entered text'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', 'ala   ma\n\nkota')
'ala ma kota'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
text = 'sample base     text with multiple       spaces'

' '.join(x for x in text.split() if x)
```

OR:

```
text = 'sample base     text with multiple       spaces'
text = text.strip()
while '  ' in text:
    text = text.replace('  ', ' ')
```