# How to reduce whitespace in Python?

Tags: python, whitespace

How do I reduce whitespace in Python from

`test = '     Good    '` to single whitespace `test = ' Good '`

I have tried define this function but when I try to `test = reducing_white(test)` it doesn't work at all, does it have to do with the function return or something?

```
counter = []

def reducing_white(txt):
    counter = txt.count(' ')
    while counter > 2: 
      txt = txt.replace(' ','',1)
      counter = txt.count(' ')
      return txt
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077897/substitute-multiple-whitespace-with-single-whitespace-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546226/a-simple-way-to-remove-multiple-spaces-in-a-string-in-python?

Comment: You call `return` in the very first iteration of your loop.  Maybe you meant to place that `return` outside of your loop?

Comment: The code doesn't really make much sense.  For one thing, it's not making any distinction between consecutive spaces vs. isolated spaces.

Comment: @alecxe: I'm curious.  You have the gold python badge, so why not close as a duplicate?  The answers that are here aren't improving on the answers there ...

Comment: @zondo decided to play it safely, wait for the OP to respond or make the problem different. But, you are right, closing. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe sorry for the question, I am new to python. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
def reduce_ws(txt):
    ntxt = txt.strip()
    return ' '+ ntxt + ' '

j = '    Hello World     '
print(reduce_ws(j))
```

OUTPUT:

' Hello World '

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expressions:

```
import re

re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', test)
>>>> ' Good '

test = '     Good    Sh ow     '
re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', test)
>>>> ' Good Sh ow '
```

`r'\s+'` matches all multiple whitespace characters, and replaces the entire sequence with a `' '` i.e. a single whitespace character.

This solution is fairly powerful and will work on any combination of multiple spaces.