# How to best replace multiple whitespaces by one (in python)?

Tags: python

In python I have, for example, the following string:

```
a = "Sentence  with     weird    whitespaces"
```

I want the same string with extended whitespaces replaced by just one, so the final string would read

```
 'Sentence with weird whitespaces'
```

I found a solution myself, but is there a better/shorter one?

```
' '.join([x for x in a.split(' ') if len(x)>0])
```

Comment: have you tried using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)?

Comment: see this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077897/substitute-multiple-whitespace-with-single-whitespace-in-python

Comment: If you're looking to make it shorter, you could replace `if len(x).0` with `if x`. Note that this doesn't make it *better*, just shorter. (Code-golf disclaimer)

Comment: Yes sure, I just saw that myself. Adding an empty string is just 'fine' (maybe not from a performance point-of-view, but still)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use:

```
import re
a = re.sub(' +',' ',a)
```

Comment: I really should use regular expressions more often .... Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. Would be cool if someone wants to elaborate on the plus sign in that regex as this a perfect example of a situation that calls for it.

Comment: @AlexanderD'Attore + sign above checks for 1 or more consecutive occurrences of a space.

Answer (score 11):

```
" ".join(a.split())
```

pulled this from one of the duplicates for your question

Comment: Right, I can omit my length check. Adding an empty string to a string does not change string. I really should call it a day...

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is already very pythonic, I often use a more readable version:

```
sentence = "Sentence  with     weird    whitespaces"

while "  " in sentence:
    sentence = sentence.replace("  ", " ")
```

(Replace double spaces by one while double spaces are in string).

Hope this helps!