# Splitting string and removing whitespace Python

Tags: python, regex, split, whitespace, strip

I would like to split a String by comma `','` and remove whitespace from the beginning and end of each split.

For example, if I have the string:

`"QVOD,  Baidu Player"`

I would like to split and strip to:

`['QVOD', 'Baidu Player']`

Is there an elegant way of doing this? Possibly using a list comprehension?

Comment: Will the format of the data be the same, always?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/trimming-a-string-in-python/761825#761825). Not completely, but you can find all the answers you need there.

Comment: @Kraay89 It is not a duplicate of the question you link to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python has a spectacular function called `split` that will keep you from having to use a regex or something similar. You can split your string by just calling `my_string.split(delimiter)`

After that python has a `strip` function which will remove all whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

```
[item.strip() for item in my_string.split(',')]
```

Benchmarks for the two methods are below:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('map(str.strip, "QVOD, Baidu Player".split(","))', number=100000)
0.3525350093841553
>>> timeit.timeit('map(stripper, "QVOD, Baidu Player".split(","))','stripper=str.strip', number=100000)
0.31575989723205566
>>> timeit.timeit("[item.strip() for item in 'QVOD, Baidu Player'.split(',')]", number=100000)
0.246596097946167
```

So the list comp is about 33% faster than the map.

Probably also worth noting that as far as being "pythonic" goes, Guido himself votes for the LC. http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: @DSM Whoops, my bad. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks I tried something like this already and each part `QVOD` ect.. is placed on a new line. The answer below works well as everything is in a list.

Comment: @DanielPilch: both methods produce the same list.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Please check the updated code. This might perform almost as fast as LC.

Comment: @thefourtheye It's faster than the other version, but still noticeably slower than the LC

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Please not that it varies from machine to machine. Check the results on my machine :)

Comment: Yep you're right, I was printing item and not creating a list from the comprehension `categories = [item.strip() for item in my_string.split(',')]` silly mistake and yes it is faster, thanks!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski The arguments between LC's and the `map`, `reduce`, `filter` functions are pretty well established, so I figured it didn't need much discussion, but linked to the article to try to cover for that aspect.

Answer (score 4):

A little functional approach. `split` function, splits the string based on `,` and the each and every element will be stripped by `str.strip`, by `map`.

```
>>> stripper = str.strip
>>> map(stripper, "QVOD, Baidu Player".split(","))
['QVOD', 'Baidu Player']
```

Little timing comparison

```
import timeit
stripper = str.strip
print timeit.timeit('map(stripper, "QVOD, Baidu Player".split(","))', "from __main__ import stripper", number=100000)
print timeit.timeit("[item.strip() for item in 'QVOD, Baidu Player'.split(',')]", number=100000)
```

**Output on my machine**

```
0.553178071976
0.569463968277
```

So, both the List comprehension method and `map` method perform almost the same.

Comment: Why are you assigning `str.strip` to a variable?  Why not pass it directly -`map(str.strip, "QVOD, Baidu Player".split(","))`

Comment: @pyrospade That doesn't have to got from `str` everytime. So, little performance gain :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Really?  I would imagine that when you pass `str.strip` to `map(function, sequence)` it is getting assigned to the `function` parameter and used locally as a variable there.

Comment: @thefourtheye What version of python are you running?