# remove white space before a string character

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am having difficulty removing white space in front of the character. I am trying to parse the sample string object below:

```
Mary Whitten: {laptop: 100, tv : 5, xbox: 50, }, James Doe: {laptop: 30, tv: 3,  xbox: 5,}, Jesus Navas: {laptop: 25, tv: 3, xbox: 5},Matt Mart:{laptop:10, xbox: 10}
```

i also used .split('},') while parsing the above string. The keys that I got:

```
d=['Mary Whitten', ' James Doe', ' Jesus Navas', 'Matt Mart']
```

there are some white spaces in front of ' James Doe' and ' Jesus Navas' which I am trying to avoid because keys are sensitive to white spaces i.e d['James Doe'] is not same as [' James Doe'] because of the white space in the key. How would I avoid it? Also, I wanted to make the list items case insensitive like:

```
d=(items.lowercase() for items in d)
```

Comment: You can use `strip`. [trimming a string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6039813/3336968)

Comment: Have you tried parsing it as a [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) string?

Comment: The answers below are correct, but I cannot help wondering where you are getting this string from.  It seems like it wants to be json but isn't quite.  Are you able to change the way the string is produced to make it easier to parse?

Comment: yes i get what you are trying to say. i haven't tried using json yet. the only problem i am having is i am unable to change the white space in front of ' James Doe' key string. for instance dict={' James Doe':{laptop:10}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do that as follows:

`string.strip()`

Running this script on `" Hello "` would give `"Hello"`

For your code, you would do it as follows:

```
d = [item.strip() for item in d]

>>> d = (item.lower().strip() for item in d)
>>> print d
['mary whitten', 'james doe', 'jesus navas', 'matt mart']
```

Comment: thanks sshahank for suggestions. how can I make the list in items ignore case?

Comment: @user3399326, You can just do `string.lower()`

Comment: i don't think it's possible to change the key of a dictionary. is it? for instance i was trying to remove white space in front of James Doe key in dict={' James Doe':{...}}

Comment: @user3399326, do you mean to use dict.keys

Comment: @user3399326, No, you cannot. You will have to create a new key and delete the old one.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `strip()`, `lstrip()` and `rstrip()`. [Docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip).

For example:

```
>>> 'Mary Whitten '.rstrip()
'Mary Whitten'
>>> ' James Doe'.lstrip()
'James Doe'
>>> ' Jesus Navas '.strip()
'Jesus Navas'
```

If you only want certain characters stripped (such as only whitespace), you can feed the `.*strip` methods a character or iterable of characters, such as `.strip(" ")` or `'.rstrip("\?\.\!\n")`.

For your purpose, it looks like

```
d = (items.lower().strip() for items in d)
```

Comment: thanks Bill for the reply. btw. how would I was trying to do ignore case. how would I do that?