# How to scan through list in if statement

Tags: list, if-statement, python-3.3

I have a Python 3.3 program and I would like to have something like below work. How can I get it to check the list? It simply gives me an error!

```
        app_list = ["Item1", "Item2", Item3"]
        elif menu == "open " + in app_list:
             do_stuff()
```

Comment: Please note that whenever you say "It simply gives me an error!", we don't know what error that actually was. It's always helpful to give the actual error message in your question.

Comment: I believe it was just a popup syntax error in IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
    app_list = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
    elif menu.startswith("open ") and menu[5:] in app_list:
         do_stuff()
```

Comment: It works however I have two problems: When I return None to the program it gives me an error like 'NoneType has not attribute startswith'. My second problem is how can I do 'ors' in the if statement formatted like that? Thanks.

Comment: For handling `None`, you can do `elif menu is not None and menu.startswith(...`, but I'm not clear on what you mean by doing "ors".

Comment: Thanks. By 'ors' I mean something like "elif menu == this or menu === that:" How would that work with this?

Comment: Using `in` is like a big `or`. You could also do `elif menu == "open Item1" or menu == "open Item2" or menu == "open Item3"` to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: So how do I check for multiple conditions like 'Open ' or 'launch '?

Comment: Maybe something like the following: `if (menu.startswith("open ") or menu.startswith("launch ")) and ...`

Comment: Then how would it know what number to use in menu[]?

Comment: Well, in that case instead of hard coding an offset you can do `menu.split(" ", 1)[1]` to get everything past the first space.

Comment: Sorry if this is getting annoying but what is there is a space before the list item?

Comment: Look up [Trimming a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/trimming-a-string-in-python) for one way.

Comment: Still not sure how to do it. The article showed me how to take strip spaces and other characters off strings, but I just want the item from the list in a string like 'show me ' + item1.

Comment: Please ask a new question for this; I'm afraid this is straying further from the topic you originally asked about and I'm probably the only one who is looking here. A new question will get you better answers.