# Regex - expression error not able to get correct result

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Here's my code,

```
new_name = re.sub(r'[^A-Z a-z]', '', new_name)
new_name += '.txt'
```

Input: new_name = "Air Supply 85' [1985]"

Output what I am getting: "Air Supply  .txt"

It is recognizing the extra spaces too from ' 85' [1985]' But I want it to end the new_name as character only as 'Air Supply.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim the whitespace with .strip()

```
new_name = re.sub(r'[^A-Z a-z]', '', new_name).strip()
new_name += '.txt'
```

[Trimming a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/trimming-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @YashAgarwal `strip()` would remove the space characters from the sides of a string only.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for clarifying it for me, I did not know that.