# In parse module, how to strip spaces from the parsed value?

Tags: python, parsing, formatting

The [parse](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse) module is a useful as an inverse of `format`. Its documentation mentions (referring to the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)) that

> The align operators will cause spaces (or specified fill character) to be stripped from the parsed value. The width is not enforced; it just indicates there may be whitespace or "0"s to strip.

I would like to do something like this, but I wasn't able to find any examples of how to get this to work. For example, in its normal operation, if I use a template `"{}{}"` to match `"ab"`, I get a `Result` object which contains `'a'` and `'b'`:

```
In [1]: import parse

In [2]: parse.parse("{}{}","ab")
Out[2]: <Result ('a', 'b') {}>
```

However, if I put a space between `a` and `b` in the string, then that space alters the `Result`:

```
In [3]: parse.parse("{}{}","a b")
Out[3]: <Result ('a', ' b') {}>
```

I would like the `parse.parse` method to ignore this space and still return `'a'` and `'b'`. Is this possible and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/trimming-a-string-in-python

Comment: That post is about removing leading and trailing spaces with `strip()`, but I'm interested also in ignoring spaces in the middle of the template, as well as in a solution which uses `parse`.

Comment: try with `.replace()` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just need to replace {} with {**:^**} to parse format string.  Based on your examples, this worked based my testing.

> {:^} strips leading and trailing whitespace

```
In [1]: import parse

In [2]: parse.parse("{:^}{:^}","ab")
Out[2]: <Result ('a', 'b') {}>

In [3]: parse.parse("{:^}{:^}","a b")
Out[3]: <Result ('a', 'b') {}>

In [4]: parse.parse("{:^}{:^}","a    b"
Out[4]: <Result ('a', 'b') {}>    

In [5]: parse.parse("{:^}{:^}"," a  b ")
Out[5]: <Result ('a', 'b') {}>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down in the [documentation](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse) you linked there are explicit examples:

> And messing about with alignment:

```
>>> parse('with {:>} herring', 'with     a herring')
<Result ('a',) {}>
>>> parse('spam {:^} spam', 'spam    lovely     spam')
<Result ('lovely',) {}>
```

> Note that the "center" alignment does not test to make sure the value
>   is centered - it just strips leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a string length (and the space between the values) seems to work:

```
import parse

result = parse.parse("{1s} {1s}","a b")
print(result)  # -> <Result ('a', 'b') {}>
```