# Best way to use split and strip

Tags: python, split, strip

My function scrapes my servers for the command and outputs something along the lines of `offset=1.3682` which `metrics_emit` uses to send to our metrics collector/visualizer, datadog.

What I need to do is strip off the `offset=` part because `metrics_emit` only wants the numerical value. What would be the best way of stripping `offset=` as well as calling `strip()` on `i` so that it gets rid of all newlines and trailing/leading whitespaces?

```
def check(self):
    output = sh.ntpq("-nc rv")
    out_list = output.split(",")
    for i in out_list:
        if "offset" in i:
            self.metrics_emit('ntp.offset', i)
            break
```

Comment: Regex for `offset=([^\s]+)`?

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is:

```
i.strip().split('offset=')[1]
```

For example:

```
def scrape(line):
    return line.strip().split('offset=')[1]
```

Example:

```
>>> scrape('offset=1.3682')
'1.3682'
```

Up to you if you need to convert the output.

Answer (score 0):

> How to extract the numeric value appeared after `offset=`?

```
import re
regex = re.compile('offset=([\d+\.\d+]+)')
string = 'offset=1.3682'

match = re.search(regex, string)
if match:
    print(match.group(0)) # prints - offset=1.3682
    print(match.group(1)) # prints - 1.3682
```

**Why i prefer regular expression?** Because even if the string contains other keywords, regular expression will extract the numeric value which appeared after the `offset=` expression. For example, check for the following cases with my given example.

```
string = 'welcome to offset=1.3682 Stackoverflow'
string = 'offset=abcd'
```

> How to remove leading and trailing whitespace characters?

```
string.strip()
```

will remove all the leading and trailing whitespace characters such as \n, \r, \t, \f, space.

For more flexibility use the following

- Removes only **leading** whitespace chars: `myString.lstrip()`
- Removes only **trailing** whitespace chars: `myString.rstrip()`
- Removes **specific** whitespace chars: `myString.strip('\n')` or `myString.lstrip('\n\r')` or `myString.rstrip('\n\t')` and so on.

Reference: see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039813/5352399).

Answer (score -1):

`.strip()` for removing whitespace characters.

`.replace('offset=', '')` for removing that string.

You should be able to chain them too.

Comment: then how OP will get the numeric value part after `offset=`?

Comment: `string = 'offset=1.3682'` --> `string.replace('offset=', '').strip()` --> `'1.3682'`, which you can use `float()` on to translate it? `.replace()` and `strip()` return the new string...

Comment: Downvoting my answer and editing part of my answer in so yours gets more exposure. Nice, I like it.

Comment: i smell something is burning and by the way my answer is far away from yours. i didn't say your answer is wrong but it is not sufficient to get through in every cases.