# Trimming python string after certain characters

Tags: python

I am creating a program where I am converting bytes into a utf-16 string. However, sometimes the string will carry over because there are trailing 0's and my string will end up like: "This is my string `x00\x00\x00"`. I want to trim the string when I reach the first `\x00` or `x00` which indicates trailing 0's. How do I do this in python?

My problem is not a duplicate of another question linked in comments because trim() doesn't fully work. If I have a string that is "This is my string `x00\x00` hi there `x00\x00"` I want just "This is my string" whereas trim would return "This is my string hi there"

Comment: welcome to SO, what have you tried? Can you show us the code ?

Comment: Sounds like you want [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trimming a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/trimming-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I tried getting the index of the string and then doing string manipulations from that to try and trim the string but it did not work. I would call index("x00") on the string then subtract the index from the length and call str[-diff] where diff is length-index.

Comment: Not sure if typo, but you _must_ escape null terminators in strings using a backslash or Python will try to index your string using the three character substring "x00".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `index('\x00')` to get the index of the first null character and slice the string up to the index;

```
mystring = "This is my string\x00\x00\x00hi there\x00"
terminator = mystring.index('\x00')

print(mystring[:terminator])
# "This is my string"
```

You can also `split()` on the null characters;

```
print(mystring.split(sep='\x00', maxsplit=1)[0])
# "This is my string"
```

Comment: The second piece of code you provided worked! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip()` function can eliminate some characters that you don't want, for example:

```
a = 'This is my string \x00\x00\x00'
b = a.strip('\x00') # or you can use rstrip() to eliminate characters at the end of the string
print(b)
```

You will get `This is my string` as the output.

Comment: The problem I had in one of my examples is that there could a string like "This is my string x00\x00\x00\ hi there \x00\x00" 


I would still want the output to be "This is my string". 


I have used strip() but this edge case has been throwing me off.

Comment: try this: `b = a[0:a.find('\x00')]`