# Why is line.split('\t')[1] not equal to 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have numerous tsv file containing two columns. First column is made up ofsentences and second column is made of polarity of those sentences. the delimiter is a tabulation. I would like to extract the lines which have a polarity of "0".

I made up this small code but whatsoever it does not work and return 0 sentences.

```
    for d in directory:
        print(" directory: ", d)
        splits = ['dev1'] #,'test1','train1']

        for s in splits:

            print(" sous-dir : ", s)
            path = os.path.join(indir, d)
            with open(os.path.join(path, s+'.tsv'), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_in:
              next(f_in)
              for line in f_in:
                if line.split('\t')[1] == 0:
                  doc = nlp(line.split('\t')[0])

                  line_split = [sent.text for sent in doc.sents]

                  for elt in line_split:
                    sentences_list.append(elt)


    print("nombres total de phrases :", len(sentences_list))
```

Why is line.split('\t')[1] not equal to 0 if line is the string "Je suis levant\t0\n"

ex. of a file

```
gnfjfklfklf  0
fokgmlmlrfm  1
eoklplrmrml  0
ekemlremeùe  0
```

I would like to keep line which end with "0"

Comment: Because it's `0\n` (length 2).

Comment: Also, `split` by definition returns a string, while `0` is an int.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, do you know perhaps how can I improve in order to be able to extract the part which end with 0; I try .endswith but same result  @deceze

Comment: `line.strip().endswith('0')`…?

Comment: use strip function which removes the line breaks and then convert the result to int. `int(line.split('\t')[1].strip())`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/how-do-i-trim-whitespace-from-a-string

Comment: Before the if condition, add: `line = line.rstrip()` to get rid of the '\n' at the end of line.  Then you can change your check to `if line.split('\t')[1] == '0':` or `if line.endswith('0'):`

Answer (score 1):

After splitting you need to strip the string in order to remove the garbage that IO puts in there, such as line breaks, other tabs etc. For that Python has a `.strip()` function.

You're also doing a comparison between `String` and `Integer`, so in order for it to not fail with a type error, you must either change the code to compare strings or convert the result from file to `Integer` with `int()`.

Condition could be rewritten as:

`if int(line.split('\t')[1].strip()) == 0:`

or as:

`if line.split('\t')[1].strip() == "0":`