# How I can delete whitespace in list python

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I have a list like this, how i can delete those whitespace??

```
['\n                                                      Slot 1 \n                                                  ', "\n Sinh hoạt 11   \n                                                                      at  B304 \n 07h30' - 08h15' \nCó mặt\n", "\n Lịch sử lớp 11   \n                                                                      at  B304 \n 07h30' - 08h15' \nCó mặt\n", "\n Kỹ năng Tư duy phản biện  11   \n                                                                      at  B304 \n 07h30' - 08h15' \nCó mặt\n", ' - ', "\n Ngữ văn lớp 11   \n                                                                      at  B304 \n 07h30' - 08h15' \nChưa điểm danh\n", ' - ', ' - ']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/761825/4983469

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.strip()`:

```
l = ['\n                                                      Slot 1 \n                                                  ', "\n Sinh hoạt 11   \n                                                                      at  B304 \n 07h30' - 08h15' \nCó mặt\n", "\n Lịch sử lớp 11   \n                                                                      at  B304 \n 07h30' - 08h15' \nCó mặt\n", "\n Kỹ năng Tư duy phản biện  11   \n                                                                      at  B304 \n 07h30' - 08h15' \nCó mặt\n", ' - ', "\n Ngữ văn lớp 11   \n                                                                      at  B304 \n 07h30' - 08h15' \nChưa điểm danh\n", ' - ', ' - ']
print([x.strip() for x in l])
```