# Can i do anything to make my webscraper look better?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I got my desired output, but it is all over the place, how do I make it cleaner?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.titan.fitness/strength/dumbbells/rubber-coated-hex/rubber-hex-dumbbells-with-cast-iron-handle/HEXDBB-GROUP.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

dumbbells_availability = soup.find(class_="set-items bundle-items container")
item = dumbbells_availability.find_all(class_="row product-detail set-item")
dumbbell1 = item[0]

availability = dumbbell1.find(class_="availability").get_text()
product_name = dumbbell1.find(class_="product-name").get_text()
print(availability)
print(product_name)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Define "cleaner".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I trim whitespace from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761804/how-do-i-trim-whitespace-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Just use the `getText()` method with the `strip` argument set to `True`.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.titan.fitness/strength/dumbbells/rubber-coated-hex/rubber-hex-dumbbells-with-cast-iron-handle/HEXDBB-GROUP.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

dumbbells_availability = soup.find(class_="set-items bundle-items container")
item = dumbbells_availability.find_all(class_="row product-detail set-item")
dumbbell1 = item[0]

availability = dumbbell1.find(class_="availability").getText(strip=True)
product_name = dumbbell1.find(class_="product-name").getText(strip=True)
print(availability)
print(product_name)
```

Output:

```
availability:Out of Stock.Notify me when this is in stockSign up
5 LB Rubber Hex Dumbbells
```

Comment: it is possible to write an if then statement? if "out of stock" write something?